# How to trap virus error when uploading file in library?

Tags: 2010, document-library

I have a document library.

when i upload a file in it, i get error

"some files can contain viruses or otherwise be harmful to your computer"

How to  disable warning messages??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a system related warning than sharepoint. Please refer to this link for the details and solution provided by Microsoft.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925757